# How to add data to one table from two different form using PHP and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

1. I have one table example: ( Name,city,Occupation ,Education,hobbies,Citizen,SSN ) but 2 data entry forms.
2. In the first form If I enter the data.(Name,City,Occupation)
3. When I click one button it should go to the next form and there I should enter the rest (Education,hobbies,Citizen,SSN).

Problem..

When I go to the next form it takes it as the next record.Like
(Name,City,Occupation) is saved in one record in the database.

and when I go the nextform it saves the rest to the new record.

Please help me with this issue as I am new to this language.

PS: I am using mysql Database with Php.

Comment: Use id of row created in first form as field in second form

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting data on 2nd screen. You should update the record by using row Id of the data inserted in the first screen.

Answer (score -2):

Don't insert values from the 1st form into the db right away. 
Instead call form2 in the action part of form1.
Extract the values from form1 and populate them in hidden variables in form2....something like:

```
<form id="f2"...>
<?php
   echo "\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\" />";
?> 
</form>
```

When the second form gets submitted, extract the hidden form fields and insert them into the db in one go.